# Single button to open multiple links depending the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 5 checkbox and a common submit button. When I check a particular row and click button it has to open a particular link likewise different links to different rows.So kindly help me out using JS.Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you post some code or create a fiddle using your code https://jsfiddle.net/ we can better understand what you want so we can help you...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh Edit your original question with your Fiddle.

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh and add the jquery library

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js this is the link @leo

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh Not for me, but in your jsfiddle... lol

Comment: sorry @leo..https://jsfiddle.net/8pc6wvu2/3/ updated link

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh :) .. try to watch my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I adapted an old example. You mean something like that?

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$('#myId').click(function(){
    var files = new Array();

    //xzyId is table id.
    $('#xzyId tbody tr  input:checkbox').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert(this.value);
//open a particular link here
      }
    });     
 });
})
```

Demo : [jsfiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/phdy67b1/5/)

if you want to try to open multiple pages, the browser will block the opening of multiple pages. You can unlock this by enabling popups:
chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

demo with link : [jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/phdy67b1/8/)

EDIT: NEW QUESTION

use 'object' in html to insert multiple value:

```
value='{"one":"https://www.google.it/search?q=link1","two":"https://www.google.it/search?q=link2"}'
```

combinations:

> checkbox1 + button 1 -> link1
>
> checkbox1 + button 2 -> link2

demo:[jsfiddle3](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/wdhcjbt7/18/)

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh You are welcome :) . If the answer is ok, check the answer's flag, so that question is "resolved"

Comment: I have another problem where when I click on button 2 & select the first checkbox it has to redirect to another new page. Please check the https://jsfiddle.net/wdhcjbt7/..  (say) first checkbox & two button with each individual link. when i check first box and click first button it has to redirect to www.google.com and when I click button two it has to redirect to url www.yahoo.com

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh I believe that by "flag" Leo means accept, which is done by clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons.

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh does the new solution work properly?